# How can I associate a "print" with a process?

Tags: nextflow

I made my pipeline, and I would like to print before each process a small description of what is carried out.

I basically tried to add a "print" before each process in my script. When I run the pipeline, it just prints out all descriptions first, and then the processes start executing.

What I did :

```
// Trimming
println 'Trimming reads with AlienTrimmer'
process Trimming {
    ...
}


// Convert to fasta
println 'Convert files from fastq to fasta'
process Fastq2Fasta {
    ...
}


// Concatenate files
println 'Combine all fasta files'
reads_fasta.collectFile()


// Dereplication
if (params.prefixdrep) println 'Dereplication using prefixes'
else println 'Dereplication using full reads lentgh'
process Dereplication {
    ...
}
```

What I get :

```
* Trimming reads with AlienTrimmer
* Convert files from fastq to fasta
* Combine all fasta files
* Dereplication using full reads lentgh
[74/ee63b8] Cached process > Trimming (MOBIO2-16S)
[d7/9b16c3] Cached process > Trimming (IHMS1-16S)
[e8/821f96] Cached process > Trimming (IHMS2-16S)
[2d/bfe805] Cached process > Trimming (MOBIO1-16S)
[a0/6702b3] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (IHMS1-16S)
[c0/044dcd] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (MOBIO2-16S)
[84/344d52] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (MOBIO1-16S)
[7f/20caee] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (IHMS2-16S)
[aa/ea78e8] Cached process > Dereplication (mycobiote_16S)
```

What I want :

```
* Trimming reads with AlienTrimmer
[74/ee63b8] Cached process > Trimming (MOBIO2-16S)
[d7/9b16c3] Cached process > Trimming (IHMS1-16S)
[e8/821f96] Cached process > Trimming (IHMS2-16S)
[2d/bfe805] Cached process > Trimming (MOBIO1-16S)
* Convert files from fastq to fasta
[a0/6702b3] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (IHMS1-16S)
[c0/044dcd] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (MOBIO2-16S)
[84/344d52] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (MOBIO1-16S)
[7f/20caee] Cached process > Fastq2Fasta (IHMS2-16S)
* Combine all fasta files   
* Dereplication using full reads lentgh
[aa/ea78e8] Cached process > Dereplication (mycobiote_16S)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer it's not possible out of the box. If you really need that you can use a `print` in the script section eg:

```
process foo {
  script:
  println 'Hello'
  """
  your_command_here
  """
}
```

However you will also need to write the code to only write that message only the very first time.